# State from task_struct not defined

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, task

My question is simple. I'm reading from task_struct struct to be able to access a process state. I'm coding a custom kernel module in C to read the properties of the current processess in my machine. The state attribute is defined as a long unsigned number, and according to sched.h, that number can be interpreted as:

```
/* Used in tsk->state: */
#define TASK_RUNNING            0x0000
#define TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE      0x0001
#define TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE    0x0002
#define __TASK_STOPPED          0x0004
#define __TASK_TRACED           0x0008
/* Used in tsk->exit_state: */
#define EXIT_DEAD               0x0010
#define EXIT_ZOMBIE             0x0020
#define EXIT_TRACE              (EXIT_ZOMBIE | EXIT_DEAD)
/* Used in tsk->state again: */
#define TASK_PARKED             0x0040
#define TASK_DEAD               0x0080
#define TASK_WAKEKILL           0x0100
#define TASK_WAKING             0x0200
#define TASK_NOLOAD             0x0400
#define TASK_NEW                0x0800
#define TASK_STATE_MAX          0x1000
```

The thing is, I'm getting a 0x0402(1026 as decimal) value as state in the task. What does that mean? How it can it be interpretated?

Comment: `0x0400 | 0x0002` meaning `TASK_NOLOAD | TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE`?

Comment: Does that mean that a 0x0402, as it's greater than TASK_NOLOAD but lower than TASK_NEW can be interpretated as a task state TASK_NOLOAD?

Comment: Bitflags like this don't necessarily fall in any particular order, so talking about the numerical values themselves is usually pointless. They're often defined sequentially, so as new features or capabilities are added, new entries get appended, more bits get used. "Lower" isn't necessarily meaningful. In other words, don't use `<` to test, always use `value & TASK_FLAG`, like in your case `if (value & TASK_NOLOAD && value & TASK_UNINTERRUPTABLE)`.